# Record iPhone's Screen and the audio with Quicktime?

Tags: iphone, audio, quicktime, soundflower, video-capture

I know that I can record the phone's screen, but I want to record my phone audio too. I prefer for it not to hear the sounds around me (due to my house being loud).

I tried soundflower and loopback. I might do it wrong. And no, its not same as Screen recording, its Movie recording. I'm doing Walkthrough for the game which has voice characters.

iPhone 5C
Mac 10.11.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any third-party service; This feature is built right into QuickTime. So just connect your iPhone to your Mac, open QuickTime, click on File > New Movie Recording (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>), and it will show your iPhone screen. But in order to record it's *audio* too, click the little downward arrow next to the record button, and under "Microphone" choose "(your name)'s iPhone" (by the way if it doesn't show you your iPhone's screen make sure to select your iPhone under "Camera" too, though it should be selected by default). Then just hit record and it should do the trick.

Comment: Meaning it record sounds silence? For example, TV are blasting in room and quicktime records it as well?

Comment: No, not at all. It says "Microphone", bit it's actually just "Audio Input". Just like camera is "Video Input". If you set both to your iPhone, it'll record your iPhone screen and audio, straight from the device. No data from the physical world.

Comment: I see, can I plug in headphones to my phone and it still record audio?

Comment: @AngelinaG. I'm pretty sure, though you might want to check for yourself

Comment: It works! I forgot to turn off the silence mode. Thank you dear <3

Comment: @AngelinaG. Always glad to help :)