# Can an iPhone capture as a sound file the sounds coming out of the receiver in the dial portion of a call?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to record the ringing noise made when I use the phone app to call someone else.

I just tried using control center's screen recording with microphone turned on, but whenever the phone call starts, no audio is recorded.

How might I record the tones and beeps and boops that I hear when a phone call begins?

Comment: I'm assuming you want the phone to self record this and [not use a Mac to make the recording](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246267/5472), correct?

Comment: Have you considered a Bluetooth call recorder?  It acts as a bluetooth headset (and you have to use it to speak/hear) but it has recording capabilities built in.

Comment: This is a really good question. I have wanted to record calls for for ever now!